# spark submit in client machine

Tags: eclipse, scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am running Spark Twitter sentimental analysis code in eclipse in my local system. All hadoop and spark cluster setup in server. Is it possible to run in my local system where cluster setup is not their?

If yes please guide me how.
While running I was giving arguments as

```
> --class com.dhruv.Predict \
> --master spark://<spark cluster ip>:7077 \
> --num-executors 2 \
> --executor-memory 512m \
> --executor-cores 2 \ target/twittersentiment-0.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar \
> hdfs://tmp/tweets/dataset.csv trainedModel \
> --consumerKey  \
> --consumerSecret  \
> --accessToken  \
> --accessTokenSecret
```

But its not working. Please guide me

Comment: `--master spark://your.server:7077`?

Comment: I have edited my question. i gave same but its not working.

Comment: Two more: First, jar file must be globally visible, for example it must be on each cluster machine in the same directory or in hdfs

Comment: If it's still not working, please provide us some logs - local machine logs, cluster logs

Comment: Yes thanks, ts working. But it giving me this exception Exception in thread "main" scala.ScalaReflectionException: class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection in JavaMirror with primordial classloader with boot classpath [D:\desktop\eclipse\plugins\org.scala-lang.scala-library_2.11.8.v20160304-115712-1706a37eb8.jar;D:\desktop\eclipse\plugins\org.scala-lang.scala-reflect_2.11.8.v20160304-115712-1706a37eb8.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program] not found.

Comment: Posted answer to make it easier to read for others. This problem deserves new question with more detailed log

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment:

File must be globally visible, so it should be in the same path on each machine or in distributed file system, for example in HDFS

Copy your JAR to each machine or to HDFS